# Tying double knot of garbarge bag

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, shabbat, melacha-creative-work

I remember seeing in a Shu"t that one is allowed to tie a double knot of something that will be going into the garbage since one doesn't care about it. Has anyone seen this opinion anywhere. I do know most hold it is problematic based off Rashis opinion that it will stay tied for more than a week,but looking for the idea mentioned above.

Comment: According to standard halacha, staying tied for the extended time means one cannot even make a bow on top of the knot. I'm sure you know that, but I'm just pointing it out to whoever might read something else into your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[R. Yitzchak Abadi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Abadi) (Ohr Yitzchak [1:175](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&st=&pgnum=195)) rules it is permitted to make a knot on a garbage bag that is going to be thrown out since it cannot be called a *kesher shel **kayama**.*

Comment: Nice! Now it makes sense

Comment: @oliver i must protest That Rabbi Abadi is vaguely quoting Shaarei Teshuva as a proof that tying a belt with a double knot is permitted because one is inevitably going to untie the belt to undress,  פשט המנהג לקשור שני קשרים בחגורתו אשר במתניו שאינו של קיימא, but here is different as with a garbage bag, the double knot won't inevitably get untied. so  we should follow the Rema in this case *not* to tie a double knot. -  וי"א שכל קשר שאינו עשוי להתיר באותו יום עצמו מקרי של קיימא

Comment: @sam please take a look at the previous comment

Comment: @user15464 OP asked for a source for a particular opinion; I believe I supplied OP with one. Are you now protesting R. Abadi’s opinion or are you protesting my answer [and maintain that R. Abadi doesn’t say what I wrote]? (IIANM, you and I already debated this topic.)