# Tying and untying knots on Shabbos & Yom Tov

Tags: melacha-creative-work, tying-knots-kosheir

Someone tied a garbage bag with a double knot (due to distraction by talking) on Yom Tov. He then quickly opened the top knot as if to "undo" the melacha.
A) Did he transgress "tying"? 
B) Did he transgress "untying"? 
C) Assuming the answer to A) is yes, did he rectify it by untying it?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/107146/tying-double-knot-of-garbarge-bag?r=SearchResults

Comment: Just take note that the accepted answer there has a source which doesn't mention double knots explicitly and the one presenting the answer assumes it is talking about. All discussions surrounding that point in the comment section were deleted.