# Pulling a garbage bag's drawstring on Shabbos (Tofer)

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work

In [this](https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol3Issue14.pdf) article it says that halacha is that pulling a a sewn-string that brings together disparate pieces is meleches tofer. Nevertheless, pulling the drawstring of a garbage bag is mutar "because the opening is wide." My question is that the Bais Yosef [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef%2C_Orach_Chaim.340.5.1?lang=bi) quotes the Yereim (without citing any disagreement) that even in such a situation if it is left to last a long time it is forbidden. This is echoed by the Mishna Berurah [340:29](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.340.28?lang=bi). Since garbage bags are drawn without intention to open them back up (usually), why are they permitted?

Comment: https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/pulling-a-thread/#ftn5 - "This may be done even if one plans to leave it tightened permanently, as the above is not similar at all to sewing being that its holes [which contain the draw strings] are large and the string itself is not at all similar to a thread. "

Comment: Not that it is accepted by all, but I do know many Poskim rely on it as a part of a heter - Rabbi Abadi in Ohr Yitzchok 1:175 says that since the garbage bag is meant to be thrown in the garbage truck and at that point you could not care less if it opens, it is not a kesher shel kayama. https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&st=&pgnum=195

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/107146/tying-double-knot-of-garbarge-bag

Comment: @Chatzkel I was thinking along similar lines, as there is such a discussion by boneh as well that I have seen in regards to constructing temporary medical devices. As you imply, however, that approach is very contested. Not that I'm weighing in, but this article doesn't phrase it like it's a big machlokes, so assume there must be more to it.

Comment: @Dov Interesting...I am confused as to how/if this fits with the sources I quote (/where it diverges from them) and how it fits with requirement "C" in his summary (which sounds in line with the sources I quote).

Comment: I don’t recall seeing anyone in writing that argues, but when I learned it in Yeshiva I was told most rabbonim do not rely on it lchatchila. It’s a nice svara but ultimately you are not untying it practically.

Comment: The article could be using a different approach, namely, that pulling the strings together might not be tofer to begin with. Then, in addition to this svara they’ll be meikel